# Hard Light Color Gradient Over Photo

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photoshop-effects, gradient

Anyone know how to make a gradient like attached with the underlying photo standing out with white highlights? The soldier image is the sample I am trying to replicate with the guy in the suit with computer.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where is it failing?

Comment: I've tried making the source image black and white, adjusting contrast, and placing a multiply gradient fill layer over it.

Comment: Place a "screen" photo on top of the gradient possibly

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that skilled at photoshop. What is a "screen" photo?

Comment: I've added an answer. I assumed since you seem to know what "multiply" is, you'd also know what "screen" is.

Answer (score 1):

Simply place a photo on top of a gradient layer and set the photo bending mode to `Screen`.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!